# Comparing two date / times to find out if 5 mins has lapsed between the two times php

Tags: php, date

I need to compare two dates to show an edit link if it is within 5 mins after the post was made, in PHP. If more than 5 minutes have passed, don't show anything.

```
$answer_post_date = get_the_time("Y-m-d");

$current_date = date("Y-m-d");

$formated_current_date = strtotime($answer_post_date);
$formated_answer_post_date = strtotime($current_date);
```

At this point I have two values:

```
1274414400 ($formated_current_date)
1276056000 ($formated_answer_post_date)
```

I am not sure what to do next to check if the current date/time is > 5 mins from the answer post date.

Any suggestions would be great.

All I really need the answer to be is a Boolean (yes/no) and if yes, display the minuets left to show the link to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only handling dates, how are you supposed to know if the difference is 5 minutes?

Anyway, I'd say the majority of the PHP code that uses the default PHP functions is at least somewhat broken. The problem is you, despite a unix timestamp storing the correct point in time something happens, it does not store timezone information. See [here](http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html).

So, forget using only `date` and `strtotime`. Use the [datetime extension](http://www.php.net/datetime).

Store in the database the Unix timestamp and the timezone (by timezone I mean e.g. `Europe/Lisbon`). Then:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
$answer_post_date = new DateTime("$timestamp");
$answer_post_date->setTimeZone($tz);
$current_date = new DateTime("now", $tz);

$diff = $current_date->diff($answer_post_date);
if ($diff->format("a") > 0 ||
        $diff->format("h") > 0 ||
        $diff->format("m") >= 5) {
    //more than 5 minutes have passed
}
```

Of course, for comparing dates, you can always compare the timestamps.

Comment: I dont have that timezone i just have the worpdress get_the_time() which mimics date()

Comment: @estern I was just making a larger point. Pass the `DateTime` constructor no timezone and it will use the default on, just like `date`.

Comment: @estern Upgrade. PHP 4 is not supported anymore (hell, not even PHP 5.1 is). You're exposing yourself to security problems.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of what you need to do:

```
$delta = ($formated_current_date - $formated_answer_post_date) / 60; // in minutes
if ($delta < 5) {
    // show $delta
}
```

EDIT: Like others pointed out, this alone will not fix all of the issues at hand. As I see it, the smallest change to your current code would be to use a date format with higher granularity - such as `"Y-m-d H:i:s"`. This being enough, like others pointed out, is contingent on the post's date being in the same timezone as your system.

Comment: The problem is his timestamps do not include time information.

Comment: I agree that's one of his problems .. I interpreted the question as him needing hints on the comparison syntax though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need to do a round-trip to a string format and back, regardless of how efficient or reliable it is.

`date()` will default to calling `time()` which you can call directly and get the current time in seconds as a Unix epoch timestamp (which is what you're trying to end up with in `$formated_answer_post_date`). You need to look in the WordPress docs to find the equivalent based on the post's value.

Then you can do a simple comparison of seconds. 5 minutes is 300 seconds.

You will still need to check that the code can assume the timezones of both values will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didnt think of the variable for time zone and @Artefacto pointed that out to me. I think that i am going to change my game plan to just allow that user to edit at anytime after the post has been done.